# Testing an Activity which uses a ContentResolver

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

In my app, I have an Activity, which is basically a form for the user to enter data which is then inserted into a database table via a `ContentResolver`. How do I test this Activity?

My first attempt was to use `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` which gives me full instrumentation to simulate entering data. However, the underlying `ContentProvider` is not closed and destroyed between each test, which leaves the database in an unknown state at the beginning of subsequent tests.

My second attempt was to use `ActivityUnitTestCase` and inject a mock context that can clean up the database for each test. However, this doesn't allow me to enter text or click on buttons in the activity as it is never actually drawn on the test device.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that what you've been using is intended for library development

You should look at the monkey binary [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) , which works great for me.

If you're not satisfied with it you could use [monkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) which provides more control over the tests you're running.

Edit :
As far as the database testing goes , cant you use the sqlite3 binary for a simple query after each test?

Edit2:
I am thinking of a .sh script that does the following :

1. Runs monkey for a while - you can specify the number of events for the monkey to send
2. Invoke sqlite3 with a query that would check the database integrity into a log file (sqlite3 command can take sql query as a second parameter, and you can use ">" to write the output into some file)
3. Repeat.

There are tons of examples for .sh scripting on the net so you shouldn't have problem with that.

I am assuming you're doing all this in adb shell, but if you're not, make sure to set all your environment variables correctly. Particularly ANDROID_ROOT, ANDROID_ASSETS and ANDROID_DATA should be set to "/system","/system/app" and "/data" accordingly . Also don't forget to "chmod" the .sh file to be executable ( chmod 777 file.sh ).

Another suggestion is to generate and keep track of the monkey random seeds so you can repeat certain inputs that are causing you problems. You can specify a seed with -s parameter.

Comment: Since my activity inserts data into an underlying database, I want to write assertions against the database to be sure that the correct data was in fact inserted. For this particular kind of testing, the randomness of monkey doesn't seem appropriate. On the other hand, MonkeyRunner seems to provide the kind of scripting that I want. Is it possible to inspect the database from a MonkeyRunner script?

Comment: Not that i know of, but it is possible to extend a monkeyRunner Plugin and then include it in your command line to do additional tests. Note that those plugins do not give you access to the Android SDK. As i said i am just using the binary and have no experience with the Runner.

Comment: "cant you use the sqlite3 binary for a simple query after each test" Do you have any suggestions about how to automate this?